# Changing observable stream while keeping subscription

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, reactivex

In RxJS, I want the subscription to persist on the stream even when the stream is changed. Below I used an interval stream to test the behaviour

```
//Works because foo$ is unchanged
let foo$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
foo$.subscribe(x => console.log(`foo$: ${x}`));

//Doesn't work because bar$ is changed
let bar$ = Rx.Observable.never();
bar$.subscribe(x => console.log(`bar$: ${x}`))
bar$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
```

[jsbin Live Demo](https://jsbin.com/zozahuloci/edit?js,console)

How do I persist the subscription while changing `bar$` stream?
Do I have do dispose the subscription and set another subscription after I change bar$?

Comment: why don't you test it? It is easy to do. I would expect barFunc to be receiving its values as usual. You don't subscribe to `foo$` but to what `foo$` references (in the moment of subscription). If `foo$` changes later, it should not change anything to the subscription. But as I said test it and tell us the result.

Comment: I've updated the code and tested on jsbin. No luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: ... Rx.Observable.never is an observable who NEVER emits a value... You could not have dreamt of a worse example for a test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general pattern in Rx is to replace state mutation with a stream of values (i.e. an observable). Here, rather than reassigning bar$, bar$ should be modeled as an `Observable<Observable<T>>` (that is, a stream of streams of values of type T). It can then be "flattened out" into a stream of values (in this case, using `switch`).

For example:

```
const bar$ = new Rx.Subject();
bar$.switch().subscribe(x => console.log(`bar$: ${x}`));
bar$.onNext(Rx.Observable.fromArray([1,2,3]));
bar$.onNext(Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(3));
```

https://jsbin.com/firoso/edit?js,console,output